# MySQL: SUM in WHERE and WHERE last relationship row is more than 2 weeks ago

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Frontend dev here trying to get a query working.
A bit of context, we have a site where users can keep track of time and our goal is to get them to 1000 hours of time tracked.
For this we have:

1. a pretty default users table, with a column track_outdoors (0 or 1, since they can enable or disable it) and a meta column (json field)
2. A timers table, where each row has a total_time column

What I want to do is select all users who:

- Have tracking enabled (track_outdoors = 1),
- Do not have MORE than 1000 hours total_time tracked,
- Have not received the reminder email (check if meta column has 'ac_outdoors_outdoors_reminder_sent_at')
- Where the last time they tracked time was more than 2 weeks ago

I've got the basic part done, which is retrieving the users who have enabled tracking, together with their total time tracked:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.firstname,
    u.track_outdoors,
    SUM(t.total_time) AS total
FROM
    users AS u
    LEFT JOIN timers AS t ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE
    u.track_outdoors = 1
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(u.meta, '$.ac_outdoors_outdoors_reminder_sent_at') IS NULL
GROUP BY
    u.id
```

Now the two parts I'm having trouble with is using the sum to check if the total_time is smaller than 1000 and checking if the last time tracking was more than two weeks ago.
Apparently I cant use the SUM inside of the WHERE statement.
I tried searching on how to do a where last relationship is x time ago, but all I find is how to query records x days ago. (It needs to be the latest record x days ago, if that makes sense).

I think for the SUM in the WHERE statement I might need to use a subquery, but I'm not sure if that's true or how I'm supposed to do that. For the 2 weeks ago check, I understand how to check where the date is two weeks ago but not how to check that for the latest record for the user.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The condition by aggregate function cannot be used in WHERE, it must be used in HAVING. *check if the total_time is bigger than 1000 and checking if the last time tracking was more than two weeks ago* `.. HAVING total > 1000 AND MAX( {time_tracking_column} ) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment/answer provided by @Akina I was able to finish my query.

The result is:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.firstname,
    u.track_outdoors,
    SUM(t.total_time) AS total
FROM
    users AS u
    LEFT JOIN timers AS t ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE
    u.track_outdoors = 1
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(u.meta, '$.ac_outdoors_outdoors_reminder_sent_at') IS NULL
GROUP BY
    u.id
HAVING total < 1000 AND MAX( t.created_at ) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
```

So I needed to use HAVING for checking the total and MAX to check for the date of the tracker to be more than two weeks ago.